# Closed question, but still want to continue discussion

Tags: discussion

[Prevent excel from considering date based on system's date format](https://superuser.com/questions/1198551/prevent-excel-from-considering-date-based-on-systems-date-format)

Based on the question I flagged this as duplicate and it got closed. However, it seems it is not *exact* duplicate as I thought.

As you can see, the OP still looking for answer despite the referred answered question, and I can quite see why.

So, what is the proper response to this?

Asking for reopen? Keep commenting? Or open a Chat room?

Answer (score 6):

Comments aren't *really* meant for "getting an answer", especially where it's a closed question. They're meant for clarification and to a lesser extent letting the user know why the question was closed in this case.

We don't particularly *encourage* people to use chat that way either. It's somewhat messy, not all that easy to find, and if folks decide it's "easier" to bypass the main sites and ask on chat all the time, it kind of defeats the purpose of having a QA site.

Edits would throw a closed question back into the reopen queue but by the looks of it we need *pretty* significant fixes for it to not be a duplicate (and spelling/grammar fixes wouldn't hurt either).

Answer (score 5):

#### So, what is the proper response to this?

To reopen a closed question the following needs to happen:

- The OP should edit his question to explain clearly why the duplicate doesn't work for him.
- Someone with sufficient reputation should then vote to reopen.

Both of these actions will put the question in the reopen review queue, where it will be seen by 3K+ users who will decide if it should be reopened or not.